# How to import 20 image files as slides in PowerPoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How can I import 20 image files into my presentation, where each image is on a separate slide?  I have PowerPoint for Mac 2011.

Thanks

Comment: How often do you have to do this? What's wrong with creating a blank slide 20 times and then drag n' dropping each image per slide?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Well I tried googling for how to import multiple image files, and they told me to create a photo album, but apparently that's only available in the Windows version.